# Creating global controls in Labview

Tags: global-variables, controls, labview

I have a complicated GUI with many contols and sub VIs. I pass the values of my controls to the sub VIs and when I need to change some property of the controls (i.e. disable them), I pass the references.

My Block Diagram is far too big. So I want to use global variables. Then I could display the sub VIs as icons and save a lot of space on the diagram (my sub VIs have a lot of inputs).

But what should I do about the controls whose properties I want to change (now I pass references to them instead of just values)? When I use a global variable, I can get only its value, nothing more.

I could create global references to all my controls and use them in my sub VIs, but then the sub VIs would be very unclear and I want to avoid it.

So how can I create a global control in Labview?

Edit: I have a control called "Motor ID" in my main VI. When I want to connect to the motor in a sub VI, I pass a reference to that control. In the sub VI I use the property "disabled" to disable the control if the connection was established.

When I use a global variable to hold the motor ID, all I will be able to do is to get the motor ID and connect with the motor. But I won't be able to disable the control in my main VI.

Comment: So it is unclear to me. You do not know how to create global variable in LabVIEW, or how to Change controls properties in subVIs?

Comment: I know how to create a global variable in Labview. I also know how to change control properties in sub VIs, but only if I have a reference to my control in the sub VIs. What I don't know is how to change properties of controls using global variables.

Comment: You should consider using a tab control if your diagram is that cluttered that you feel the need to use global variables to clean it up.

Comment: I already have a tab control. The case structure takes up the most space.

Comment: I decided to make this a potential answer instead of a comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your comments I would say you can not change properties of your controls/indicators using globals.

Remember Globals transfer only the VALUE of the controls not ever properties associated with them. You have to pass control references to subVIs to be able to change control's properties on the FP.

I can suggest you to group all your controls in one Cluster, create the reference of that cluster and pass one reference to your subVI to avoid code complication. Or you can just group all references of your controls into cluster and pass one wire to your subVI.

Hope this will help.

Answer (score 3):

I would say you have several options, and unfortunately all of them likely require significant restructuring of your code, and therefore a lot of time. Two of them have already been stated by others, but I will re-iterate here.

1. Use Global References
2. Organize related data into clusters
3. Utilize Sub-Panels
4. Look into [X-Controls](http://www.ni.com/tutorial/3198/en/)
5. Use multiple windows and Sub-VIs instead of tabs.
6. Use the [CVT API](http://www.ni.com/example/30326/en/) to store your globals

And going deeper into each option...

1. Using global references simply means you store a reference to all of your controls into their own global variable which you then call within your VI's. With the global reference you can modify any property, get or set values, essentially control the VI as if you had access to the front panel from that VI without having to pass the reference through an input node. This can create a mess for initialization and requires you to create references for each control, but it might be worth it for the functionality and readability.
2. Organizing data into clusters is always going to look nicer on the block diagram, and I would encourage doing this as much as possible. Always look for an opportunity to put data into clusters. Be careful though, because if you pass a cluster into a sub-vi, you pass ALL the data from the cluster into the sub-vi, and if you have items which take up a lot of memory this can slow the program down. They are useful to organize and clean up your diagram, but pay attention to how you pass them around your program.
3. Sub-panels essentially allow you to have a central front panel and swap out VI's whenever you feel like it. You can control the execution of the VI through invoke nodes, and choose which VI is shown in the sub-panel by passing its reference to the sub-panel block on your diagram. This is very useful if you have several independent operations which don't all have to be displayed at once.
4. X-Controls are similar to sub-panels, except way cooler. An X-Control is essentially a combination of a cluster and a sub-panel rolled into a class which you can drop on your front panel. It is represented on the block diagram as a normal control, but data manipulation and processing is handled independently within an internal event structure. X-Controls can be slightly confusing, and if used improperly can actually complicate your code more than clean it up. Make sure you fully understand how they behave before attempting to integrate them into your code.
5. If you can partition your code into multiple windows than you can have a control VI which runs a state machine that determines which window is displayed to the user. This method is very closely related to the sub-panel method. Any data which is used by all VI's can get stored into globals, and might work well with the CVT API mentioned next.
6. I don't have much experience with the CVT (Current Value Table) API, but I know it can be fairly powerful if used correctly. In essence, the CVT allows you to store all your values into globals, but you access them with keys instead of by dropping a global onto your diagram. The key's are strings that you assign to the global at creation. (They can be created at run-time and don't have to be assigned beforehand!)

Barring the above suggestions, the quickest implementation would be to use an event loop which responds to front panel activity as required. Create all of the globals you need to represent your data and use them in your VI's as needed to remove inputs. If the user updates a front panel item that has an associated global, than update the global. Be careful to avoid race-conditions, and try to write to the globals from only one location if possible (the CVT library helps avoid race conditions as it uses functional global variables). In a parallel loop, update your indicators from their associated globals.

In conclusion, there are lots of ways to clean up your block diagram and your front panel, but in general it's best to consider structuring your code from the beginning in a way that avoids clutter!

Answer (score 0):

You may want to just investigate subpanels. A subpanel on your top-level VI is a single control that hosts the panel of a subVI. You can open a VI reference to your subVI and put its panel in the subpanel control. Then the subVI just has to update controls on its own panels... no control references involved.

Comment: Thanks, but I use some controls in many subVIs, so it won't help. But this is a nice trick to remember.

Comment: The same control in multiple subVIs? That is highly unusual in a well-designed LV program. Not only are such designs prone to race conditions, they are pretty inefficient for data movement. If your program has a lot of unexplainable bugs, you might look long and hard at this as a possible source of the problem. (I'm not saying don't do it -- it works for some people -- I'm just saying my broad experience with many LV users says it is a problem more often than not.)

Comment: This is my first program in Labview - so probably my it isn't well designed. I hope it doesn't have any bugs - it works how it is suppoded to, but I have to clean up the Block Diagram. Maybe the same control isn't a good choice of word - the same variable (i.e. comport number or ID of my device). Why is it unusual and what's wrong with it? I'd be grateful for any suggestions - I'm learning Labview.

Comment: > it works how it is suppoded to
  ---  Good enough. :-)

Comment: It is unusual because you generally want only one VI hierarchy working on computing any given value, and you can feed that back up to callers to aggregate together for display to the user. If you start having to have multiple sections of your code working on the same value, it gets weird. There are some exceptions... a string control could be a log of events in the system and many different parts of your code might be appending onto that string, but even there, you generally create one subVI to encapsulate the string refnum. So your architecture does happen from time to time, but rarely.

Comment: " it gets weird" I mean you have race conditions where one part of the code overwrites the value of another part or you have read-modify-write races throughout your code. And it just gets hard to debug who is in charge of what.